# Android 13 notification permission

Tags: push-notification

I'm trying to implement the new notification runtime permission introduced in Android 13.
I have noticed that the code requires implementation also of shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale. However is not clear when this function returns true in order to show an educational ui.
Can you help me to understand?

Answer (score 1):

If user has already blocked it from Settings `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()` returns false. So there is no need to show an educational UI and request for permission. In that case the user can open notifications from settings only.